# reflect.Value.Set using unaddressable value

Tags: go, go-gorm

```
g.GET("/", func(c echo.Context) error {
    var users []models.User
    err := db.Find(users).Error
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    return c.JSON(http.StatusOK, users)
})
```

this is the code for getting and displaying users from table using slice is resulting following error from gorm

> reflect.Value.Set using unaddressable value

Comment: This is more generic thatn `go-gorm`. `go-yaml`'s `Unmarshal` suffers the same issue when you pass it something that's not properly ampersanded. (Not the technical term, but it is what it is)

Answer (score 77):

You have to call Find with a pointer to the slice.

```
err := db.Find(&users).Error
```

relevant Gorm documentation: http://jinzhu.me/gorm/crud.html#query

Comment: then i got a nil reference error i solved it by including driver

Comment: and create users slice before:  users = make([]models.User,0)

Answer (score 26):

Just to add clarification to S.Diego answers, changing this:

```
err := db.Find(users).Error
```

to this:

```
err := db.Find(&users).Error
```

the error says, the variable users is not addressable, because it is not a pointer.

Answer (score 11):

In a very similar fashion to the accepted answer (but in a slightly different context), and an error that I keep making in different projects:

```
func migrate(db *gorm.DB) {
    db.AutoMigrate(User{}, Activity{})
}
```

becomes

```
func migrate(db *gorm.DB) {
    db.AutoMigrate(&User{}, &Activity{})
}
```

Notice the ampersands.